# How to fix this warning : "ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part"

Tags: python, matplotlib, fftpack

My task is to lower the dimension of the equation (by the second spatial coordinate where it is necessary by condition) using the integral Fourier transform, to develop and implement a numerical algorithm for solving the problem by the finite element method for a one-dimensional Helmholtz equation. Check the correctness of the solution in one of the ready-made finite element packages to investigate parametrically the solution of the problem.

Semi - analytical FEM:

[image]
Apply the Fourier transform on x.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack

def solve_helmholtz_equation():
    # Setting parameters
    k1 = 1
    k2 = 2
    y_min = 0
    y_max = 2

    # Setting the range of values of x
    x_min = -10
    x_max = 10
    n_x = 1000
    x = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, n_x)

# Setting the range of y values
    n_y = 1000
    y = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, n_y)
 # Setting the value of the function u(x, y)
    u = np.zeros((n_x, n_y))

    # Setting initial and boundary conditions
    for i in range(n_x):
        if abs(x[i]) <= 1:
            u[i, 0] = 1
        else:
            u[i, 0] = 0

    u[:, -1] = 0

    # We perform the integral Fourier transform in x
    u_hat = fftpack.fft(u, axis=0)

   # Building a solution in the spatial domain
    u_new = np.zeros((n_x, n_y))

    for j in range(1, n_y):
       # We define the parameter k for this interval y
        if 0 < y[j] <= 1:
            k = k1
        else:
            k = k2

        # Integral Fourier transform of the inverse wavelet
        u_new[:, j] = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.ifft(fftpack.fftshift(u_hat[:, j-1] * np.exp(-1j * k * (y[j] - y[j-1])))))

    # Plotting the solution
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    plt.figure()
    plot = plt.pcolor(X, Y, u_new.real, shading='auto', cmap='hot')
    plt.colorbar(plot)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('Solution of the Helmholtz equation')
    plt.show()

solve_helmholtz_equation()
```

The main error in this part of the code is:

```
u_new[:, j] = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.ifft(fftpack.fftshift(u_hat[:, j-1] * np.exp(-1j * k * (y[j] - y[j-1])))))
```

Comment: That line has `-1j`.  Thats a complex number, as in `(0-1j)`.  Looks like a typo.

Comment: I do have to say, that's one of the more insidious typos I've encountered.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen
and what if the problem is related to the location of fftshift, which should be applied only to the array u_hat[:, j-1].

Comment: @MarkTolone is this a typo?

Comment: You tell me.  Do you want an imaginary number in your formula?  I don't know what your formula is supposed to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts what exactly is the typo?

Comment: Maybe you mean `-1 * j`  or just `-j`?  This refers to the variable `j` and not the imaginary number `-1j`.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is that `j` is used by electrical engineers for imaginary numbers and  `i` is used by mathematicians.  Python uses `j` as in: `cmath.sqrt(-1) == 1j`.  Probably not what you intended.

Comment: @MarkTolone
This line combines the processes of the inverse Fourier transform (ifft) and the fftshift shift applied to the function u_hat[:, j-1] with the scalar product by the exponent e^(-1j * k * (y[j] - y[j-1])). Next, the resulting value is assigned to the element of the array u_new[:, j]. This process is performed for each value of j in the range from 1 to n_y. As a result, we obtain a solution of the Helmholtz equation for the given parameters and boundary conditions in the spatial domain.

Comment: Yeah, talking completely over my head for that math.  Again, do you intend to have an imaginary number in your formula.  If not, fix it.

Comment: Actually, looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69040586/casting-complex-values-to-real-discards-the-imaginary-part-using-fft?rq=2 and the fact that we have no full traceback of the line causing the problem, it may be you are just using matplotlib to plot complex numbers and that isn't supported.

Comment: @MarkTolone 
As I understand it, this error occurred due to the fact that when multiplying complex numbers by real numbers, the imaginary part is discarded. I tried to fix this error by converting the multiplication result to a real data type. This can be done using the np.real() function, which returns the real part of a complex array

Comment: @MarkTolone 
. В моем случае можно изменить строку кода на следующую: u_new[:, j] = np.real(fftpack.ifft(fftpack.fftshift(u_hat[:, j-1])) * np.exp(-1j * k * (y[j] - y[j-1]))) Похоже, что это сохранит только действительную часть результата умножения комплексных чисел, тем самым устранив предупреждение об ошибке

Comment: The key is, when you say `e^(-1j * k * (y[j] - y[j-1]))`, did you intend that first component to be `negative j` where `j` is the loop variable, or did you intend that to be the complex number `-i`, meaning the negative square root of -1?

Comment: @Alina: Why not answer your own question? @Mark and @Tim: the OP meant a complex number by ```1j```, so not a typo.